# Angular 1.4.8 / lodash parse an array of objects with conditional parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

**DEV TOOLS**

- Angular 1.4.8,lodash 4.0

**FINAL SOLUTION**

Building off Derek's code contribution below I've landed on the following. Had to adjust as _.property() or _.map() chained with a _.find generates an exception when parsing undefined:

```
            var getProfileImage = function(images) {
                var defaultPath = 'images/profile/darthvader.jpg';
                if(!images || !images.length) return defaultPath;

                if (images) {
                    thumbnail = _.find(images, {type: 10});
                    return  thumbnail ? _.has(thumbnail, 'data_url') ? thumbnail.data_url : defaultPath: defaultPath;
                }
            },
```

**OBJECTIVE**

I'm sure this is a noob question as I'm new to JS and apologize in advance if it obvious. Below is a method that parses images to find a profile image. If image exists then extract 'data_url' property. If the image or image type might not exist replace with a generic path. Note this method works, but seems verbose.

**QUESTION**

Using the above mentioned tools is there a more concise way to achieve the same result?

**(sidenote)** I've attempted to use the lodash `chain()` method along with `_.pluck()` but I keep getting a type error, which I suspect is the result if find or filter returns an undefined

> TypeError: chain() ..._.pluck is not a function

*Method mentioned above:*

data example (simplified):

```
$images = [
 {id: 1,
 type: 10,
 data_url: base64string
 },
 {id: 2,
 type: 11, // note: not equal
 data_url: base64string
 }
];
```

method is call from a directive template with the code below. Removed directive code for brevity sake:

```
    "<img class='thumbnail__image' ng-src='{[{conversation.getImage(comment.profile.images)}]}'/>,
```

method

```
    var getProfileImage = function(images) {
        var thumbnail = null;
        var path = 'images/profile/generic-thumbnail.png';

        if (images) {
            thumbnail = _.find(images, function(image) {
                return image.type === 10;
            });
            if (_.isUndefined(thumbnail)) {
                thumbnail = path;
            } else if (_.has(thumbnail, 'data_url')) {
                thumbnail = thumbnail.data_url';
            }
            return thumbnail;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Would help to have more context about where and how this is used and what basic data structure is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question would be more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

But here is an example of how you could clean up your code:

```
var getProfileImage = function(images) {
    var defaultPath = 'images/profile/generic-thumbnail.png';

    if(!images || !images.length) return defaultPath;

    var thumbnailPath = _(images)
        .find({ type: 10 })
        .map('data_url')
        .value();

    return thumbnailPath ? thumbnailPath : defaultPath;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`_.pluck` would definitely make your code more concise but it has been removed from `lodash` *4.0.0*: [lodash 4.0.0 changelog](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog).

You can now use `_.map` in place of `_.pluck`.